# $A^2$ and $A^3+A$ are diagonalizable, prove $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

In a finite dimensional vector space, suppose $A^2$ and $A^3+A$ are diagonalizable, how to prove $A$ is diagonalizable?

---

What I can know is the minimal polynomial of $A^2$ and $A^3+A$, but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: $A^2 = PDP^{-1} \implies A=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$

Comment: @DougM: That may not work if the field isn't algebraically closed.

Comment: @Doug doesn't work if $A$ is non-zero and nilpotent

Comment: @carmichael561 diagonizable doesn't depend on the field, since if two matrix are similar in C, they are similar in R

Comment: @89085731: It absolutely depends on the field. Try diagonalizing $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 I mean if two similar matrix are in R

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Suppose $A$ is in Jordan form. Since $A^2$ is diagonalizable, any Jordan blocks associated with a non-zero eigenvector have size $1$. Since $A^3+A$ is diagonalizable, any eigenvalues associated with $0$ are of size $1$.

The conclusion follows.

---

For instance, consider for any $\lambda\neq 0$
$$
A=\pmatrix{\lambda & 1\\ 0&\lambda} \implies
A^2= \pmatrix{\lambda^2 & 2\lambda\\ 0&\lambda^2}
$$
Note that $A$ has only $1$ eigenvector (more accurately, a $1$-dimensional eigenspace) associated with $\lambda^2$ and no other eigenvalues. So, $A^2$ is not diagonalizable, and no matrix with $A$ as a diagonal subblock is diagonalizable.

Comment: I don't understand the first assertion, since the square of the Jordan form may not be the Jordan form of $$A^2

Comment: It won't be, but it will be *similar* to that Jordan form. That is, the square of a non-zero Jordan block is only diagonalizable if the block is size $1$.

Comment: could u write it more detailed, I have some difficulty understanding your answer, thanks

Comment: See my latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

The example $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ shows that the assertion is false without some additional assumptions. After all,
$$ A^2=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} $$
is diagonalizable, as is
$$ A^3+A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=0$$
but $A$ is not diagonalizable.

If the field is algebraically closed, then Omnomnomnom's answer works.

Comment: I don't know why his first assertion that the Jordan block has size 1 is correct